# the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification problem

Tags: android

I have a custom `ListView` that get new values every time user clicks on Button. However, each time I click I get follownig error:

```
Process: com.example.transportor, PID: 20274
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131230978, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.example.transportor.CustomAdapterLF)]
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1562)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForTap.run(AbsListView.java:3265)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5237)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

I'm invoking `notifyDataSetChanged()` via `customAdapterLF.notifyDataSetChanged();`

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_facture);

        final ListView productListe = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.productList);
        arrayListLF = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayListLF.add(0, new Product("5","ala","4500"));
        customAdapterLF = new CustomAdapterLF(this,arrayListLF);
        productListe.setAdapter(customAdapterLF);

        productListe.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"paaaap...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        addListe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if((quantity.getText().toString()!="")&&(Prix!=0.0)&&(Selected_Product!="")){
                        Listcounter++;
                        int qua = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString());
                        TotaleP = TotaleP + (Prix*qua);
                        tot.setText(TotaleP.toString() + "MAD");
                        arrayListLF.add(Listcounter, new Product("5","ala","4500"));
                        customAdapterLF = new CustomAdapterLF(new_facture.this,arrayListLF);
                        customAdapterLF.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //String newItem = "    " + quantity.getText().toString() + "   " + Selected_Product;
                        //itemList.add(newItem);
                        // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        quantity.setText("");
                        Prix= 0.0;
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inserer le quantity ou clicker sur un produit",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: why you are redefining **customAdapterLF** before **customeAdapterLF.notifyDataSetChanged();** ?

Comment: don't create a new adapter object. Use the one you created first in `onCreate()`

Comment: @BBazeae Can you please add the global variables such as ```addListe``` on which you add onClick Listener.

Comment: thanks Guys I've removed new adapter

Comment: @bbazeae Did you resolve your question?

Comment: Yeah I did I just delete the new declaration of adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use

```
  notifyDataChange()
```

by this way you will tell the list view to refresh the data and use the new one

also as recommended , if you know which item has been changed , I recommend to use

```
  notifyItemChanged(int itemIndex)
```

because you don't have to refresh the whole list again and again ( Best Practice )